# MVC4 - getting list of fields in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to safely programmatically get a list of fields that are in the View that has just posted back to a Controller?

I noticed a problem with the default implementation of the scaffolding, in

```
DB.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified
DB.SaveChanges()
```

The problem is that if I haven't included a field to be edited in the view, it is being overwritten by the default value of the field that .NET assigns when creating the object.  eg. If I have a User class with ID, Email and PasswordHash and I want to allow the user to update their Email address only, if I don't include anything for the PasswordHash field, it is reset to NULL as it is passed into the controller as NULL.  At the moment, I am working around it by retrieving the current object from the database and updating only the fields which I know are in the View from the model passed in.  That isn't such a problem for a small table, but I would like to have a general solution that I can apply across the board, especially for large tables which may during development and I don't want to have to update the code every time.

I know that I could loop through the POST variables and examine them to see what has been posted, but that creates a security issue as the user could inject additional fields that I don't want them to edit.  I suppose I could explicitly exclude ones that I don't want them to edit, but then again, I would rather not have to list those if I can avoid it as it is an extra thing to maintain.

I think that there are 2 problems here and I'm not sure either are solvable...

- Getting the View that posted back
- Establishing which fields are included in that View (I might need to construct it again temporarily to do that?)

I suppose that I can probably get away with ignoring the first one as I could just only ever use that method on the Controller for a single View.  That is still a little less neat than I'd like, but it does reduce the issue to just establishing which fields are in the View.

Comment: So far, the best idea I've got is to find the view file, read the source text in and use Regexes to locate fields.  This is messy, especially if I have partial views.  It would also involve using reflection recursively to allow for fields accessing other records via properties

Answer (score 1):

If a view needs only certain properties, create an interface with only those properties. Use this interface in the HttpGet and HttpPost methods.

And then you can use something like AutoMapper to map the viewmodel to your entity.

Comment: That's more work than just copying over the fields one at a time in the controller!

Comment: This did give me the idea to use New With {model.Email} and pass that into a function to copy properties to the item from the database.  Not quite what I was aiming for, but certainly a bit neater than what I had so +1 for that, but doesn't answer the question